# doctrine module Command Line Tool

Tags: doctrine-orm, command-line-interface, zf3

I'd like to use Commandline Tool with doctrine-module, following the Oleg Krivtsov's book Using Zend Framework 3, chapter 13.4 (about migrations).

I work on windows 10 with Xampp.
here is a copy of my cli windows

```
D:\xampp\php>php ../htdocs/userdemo/vendor/bin/doctrine-module migrations:migrate

dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../doctrine/doctrine-module/bin" &&
pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
  # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
  # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
  # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
  if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
    dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
  fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g') "${dir}/doctrine-module" "$@"

D:\xampp\php>
```

I don't understand.
Could you tell me what to do ?
Thanks

Comment: Is the problem that the script is not being run and just being echoed? It looks like a bash script and not php (which it seems you're calling it with). I'm not familiar with running scripts on windows, but you could look into that

Comment: ok I'm going to try